# Import data in derby with identity id

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am importing data to derby using `SYSCS_IMPORT_DATA`. My table has an identity columns that i want to keep because it is referenced in other tables.

I keep getting the error:

> Attempt to modify an identity column

using the following call

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_DATA (NULL,'TABLE',NULL,NULL,'DATA.DEL',NULL,NULL,NULL,0);
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753512/an-attempt-was-made-to-modify-the-identity-column-id/38850266#38850266)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i found my answer. The problem was the table, just changed the GENERATED ALWAYS for GENERATED BY DEFAULT.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the "GENERATED ALWAYS" in your tables. The solution is that you have to specify in the call those columns that you want to import in the table, excluding those that are identity columns.

Example:

CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_DATA
    (null, 'STAFF', 'NAME,DEPT,SALARY,PICTURE', '2,3,4,6', 
    'c:\data\staff.del', ',','"','UTF-8',  0);

The third parameter of the call are the columns names, and the fourth their order in the table.

More info at this link:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/tools/ctoolsimportidentitycol.html

Hope this helps in the future,
Marcos.