# An attempt was made to modify the identity column ' ID'

Tags: java, hibernate, generator, derby

I have problem with my project. My apache derby generate id, in table it works. But in app it doesnt work. In derby I set id autoincrement (start with 1, increment by 1), but i get this error:

```
> Caused by: ERROR 42Z23 : An attempt was made to modify the identity
> column ' ID'
```

.

My entity:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", schema = "KK", catalog = "")
public class UsersEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

hibernate xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping resource="mapping.xml"/>
        <mapping class="com.springapp.mvc.models.AccountEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.springapp.mvc.models.BookEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.springapp.mvc.models.UsersEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

mapping.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.springapp.mvc.models.AccountEntity" table="ACCOUNT" schema="KK">
        <id name="id" column="ID"/>
        <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
        <property name="accountprefix" column="ACCOUNTPREFIX"/>
        <property name="accountnumber" column="ACCOUNTNUMBER"/>
        <property name="bankcode" column="BANKCODE"/>
        <property name="userid" column="USERID"/>
    </class>
    <class name="com.springapp.mvc.models.BookEntity" table="BOOK" schema="KK">
        <id name="id" column="ID"/>
        <property name="title" column="TITLE"/>
        <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"/>
        <property name="userid" column="USERID"/>
    </class>
    <class name="com.springapp.mvc.models.UsersEntity" table="USERS" schema="KK">
        <id name="id" column="ID"/>
        <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
        <property name="password" column="PASSWORD"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks

Comment: so ... don't try to alter the id.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the ID table field to auto-increment then you should not try to insert an id because this is auto generated by derby.

or use Hibernate to generate you id

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: but if I delete autoincrement in derby, it only overrides one user. When I save user in session I use saveOrUpdate and this should generate id, but it doesnt

Comment: i see that you put the annotations on top of the getter, it might be that

Comment: solved with adding to mapping.xml:                                                                   <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

Answer (score 0):

If you define your table this way (either with the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` or `GENERATED AS ALWAYS` keywords)

```
CREATE TABLE Consultation (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT 
    AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
 Patient_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES PATIENT(CARDNUMBER),
 Consultation_date CHAR(20))
```

**you cannot directly insert anything into `id`. You get this error when you try to do so**. You insert data into an `Identity` field like this:

```
INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (PATIENT_ID, CONSULTATION_DATE) VALUES ('B2345', '4-8-2016')
```

This way, the id field is autogenerated for you and incremented when ever you populate a new column.

**Note** I copied the sql statements above from console in Intellij, to use in a java class, add String concatenation as appropriate:

```
 statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Consultation (PATIENT_ID, CONSULTATION_DATE) VALUES "  +
                "('2345', '4-8-2016')");
```